# Is there a way to query the list of reserved keywords in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a program that generates standard alias names per table name. In order to do so I need to make sure I do not generate an alias name that matches a sql reserved keyword (ex: 'max', 'top', 'abs' etc). I realize that I could put the generated alias name into square brackets to use a literal name regardless of reserved keywords... but I would to avoid doing so. Is there a table that can be queried that contains a list of the reserved keywords?

Comment: You really shouldn't avoid doing so. What happens if a reserve word is added in a new version after your code is generated? Adding brackets seems a lot easier than querying for reserved keywords.

Comment: The link I posted includes future keywords as well.  But I agree brackets would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own table out of this list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx